# RPI 2 B died, PP9 test point should throw 1.8v and throws only 0.02v, how do I fix this?

Tags: pi-2, power, failure

Last night I unplugged it "unsafely" and today it doesn't start.

What I get is a solid red light along with a solid green light. I have tried every possible combination (SD cards, Power supplies, OS) and it just doesn't respond.

Nothing is displayed.

I then did some research and found about the test points in the back.

pp1 (5v), pp2 (5v), pp8 (3.3v) give the appropiate values but pp9 should be 1.8v but I only get 0.02 or so so I guess the problem is there.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.S: I have another Pi2 and the pp9 value thows 1.8v as expected.

Comment: This may mean there is a 1.8V component that is fried somewhere, which I think includes the RAM (at least...), and that cannot be replaced.  I don't know if there are any potential [polyfuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) on that circuit, you could leave it unplugged for a few days and see.  Unplugging it suddenly should not cause physical damage BTW, that may be a coincidence.

Comment: I have unplugged them many times like that because of unresponsiveness during some tests, I guess that the unplugging did wreck it although it should be safe to do it.

Also, isn't the memory built in the broadcom chip?

Comment: The memory is layered on top of the SoC on some models although not the 2 -- it's the big chip on the bottom of the board, probably branded "Elpida".  Anyway, pulling the cord should not (and may not) have caused the damage, so if it is less than a year old and you have not been going crazy with overclocking you may want to investigate a warranty claim.

Comment: Oh, yeah,  you're right! I'm gonna try about the warranty claim. It's over a year old but in Spain we get 2 years by law.